# Issue installing docker in RHEL

Tags: installation, docker, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am having trouble installing docker in my **RHEL-7** VM.

First I followed this link - https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/   Every thing went well but docker isn't starting.

After some research I found the my `containerd.io` is of old (1.2) version and I need to update to 1.4 version because of below error:

> docker: error adding content digest to lease:
> sha256:31168c113862cce4cef6b16b20cdef1b126eb755492a6030ca68a9020b7eb657:
> unknown method AddResource: not implemented.

I uninstalled the old and while installing new version I am getting following issue:

> rpm -i containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
> error: Failed dependencies:
> container-selinux >= 2:2.74 is needed by containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el7.x86_64
> runc conflicts with containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el7.x86_64
> runc is obsoleted by containerd.io-1.4.6-3.1.el7.x86_64

Then I tried installing `container-selinux` package and got this error:

> rpm -i container-selinux-2.107-3.el7.noarch.rpm
> warning:
> container-selinux-2.107-3.el7.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256
> Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
> .error: Failed dependencies:
> policycoreutils-python is needed by
> container-selinux-2:2.107-3.el7.noarch
> selinux-policy >= 3.13.1-216.el7 is needed by container-selinux-2:2.107-3.el7.noarch
> selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-216.el7 is needed by container-selinux-2:2.107-3.el7.noarch
> selinux-policy-targeted >=
> 3.13.1-216.el7 is needed by container-selinux-2:2.107-3.el7.noarch

But if I see `policycoreutils-python` is already installed in my server.

> rpm -qa | grep policycoreutils-python
> policycoreutils-python-utils-2.9-14.el8.noarch

Now I am completely stuck with it and any help/suggestions would be much appriated.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the exact version of RHEL 7 you are using.  Due to the number of dependencies you are going to have to update, you probably should bite the bullet, and simply upgrade to RHEL 8 (thus by upgrading all dependencies at once).  Strictly speaking Fedora 32 (Kernel 5.6+) (or CentOS running a similar kernel version) is required for the current version of Docker

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It indeed worked. I updated the RHEL to 8 and everything went perfect :)